# Is it possible to run iarbuild.exe in dry-run mode

Tags: build, embedded, iar

I would like to know if it possible to run iarbuild.exe in dry-run mode like '-n' in Make ?

from Make help :

```
  -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                     Don't actually run any commands; just print them.
```

I did not notice for any option in the usage message, maybe a tag in the ewp (IAR project file) ?

Or is there an option to create compilation database ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid normal compilation? What is the problem you want solve with dry run?

Comment: I don't want to avoid normal compilation, I would like to get a build log (in order to generate a compilation database) but without rebuilding the whole project and redirect build log to a file. There's might be a scenario which a build takes more than a few seconds, and would like to avoid long build cycles.

Comment: So you want to avoid running compilation twice (once for the build, once for the database)? IAR can output some files that might help you (.dep and .pbi files), and IAR IDE should support redirecting build messages to the file. Not sure if that is what you are after. What information do you want to get out of it?

Comment: all the flags that are used for building each source file

Comment: In that case I would look for the pbi files, as they seem to have compiler options listed. I *think* the feature may require that some IDE option is enabled, but I don't know for sure.